# how to limit memory of a docker container in dockerfile itself

Tags: docker

I want to limit my docker container in docker file itself .I dont want to limit in the runtime.
I need to use **-XX:MaxRAMFraction=4** this value in docker file
I have a docker compose file which invokes my docker file.Can I use the options like
logging:
options:
 -XX:MaxRAMFraction=4
?
Does that work?

Comment: What have you actually tried already?  As @iabughosh’s answer suggests there are standard JVM environment variables you can set in your Dockerfile or an ENTRYPOINT script or a `docker-compose.yml` file or elsewhere.

Comment: I have a docker-compose file and I want to add into it as a envirinment variable.But it is not taking -XX:MaxRAMFraction=4.its showing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it works you can pass JAVA_OPTS as an environment variables, ex :

```
 ...
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    ports:
    - 8080
    environment:
      JAVA_OPT: "-Xms256m -Xmx1g"
```

if you are using a server that reads JAVA_OPT this should work for you, if your Docker file is running normal jar file you can pass options as parameter, ex:

java $JAVA_OPT -jar {yourjarfile.jar}

Comment: Thanx for your answer but how do  I make my container read JAVA_OPT?Do I need to add or does jvm understand directly?

Comment: I wrote that if you are running a server that reads a JAVA_OPT then no need for that other wise you will use : java $JAVA_OPT -jar {yourjarfile.jar} if it is a runnable jar.

Comment: i am using docker compose version 2.0 and am trying to add this   environment:
      - JAVA_OPT: -XX:MaxRAMFraction=18 . But running the build in jenkins showed the following error ::::  environment contains {"JAVA_OPT": "-XX:MaxRAMFraction=18"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string.Even I tried enclosing it with quotes but the same error is popping..Please help

Comment: Please post your docker-compose file

Comment: I was able to build it but my jvm in container is not able to read it even though is specified.Please help..ENV JAVA_OPTS -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false

Answer (score 0):

It worked.
I was giving - JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxRAMFraction=18" instead of - JAVA_OPTS:"-XX:MaxRAMFraction=18"...So : is doing the damage here.Thanx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS rather that JAVA_OPTS because the first one is directly read by JVM